# JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder vs org.springframework.jdbc.core.jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I understand jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate is used for sending several records to data base in one communication.
Lets say i have 1000 records to be updated, instead of 1000 communications from Application to database, the Application will send 1000 records in request.

Coming to JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder its combination of Tasks in a job.

My question is, if there is 1000 records to be processed(INSERT statements) via JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder, all INSERTS executed in one go? or one after one?

If one after one,  connecting to database 1000 times using JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder causes perf issues? hows that handled?

i would like to understand if Spring batch performs better than running 1000 INSERT staments using jdbcTemplate.update ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JdbcBatchItemWriter` uses `java.sql.PreparedStatement#addBatch` and `java.sql.Statement#executeBatch` internally (See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/c4010fbffa6b71cbcfe79d523023251ce73666a4/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcBatchItemWriter.java#L189-L195), so there will be a single batch insert for all items of the chunk.

Moreover, this will be executed in a single transaction as described in the [Chunk-oriented Processing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/step.html#chunkOrientedProcessing) section of the reference documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  if there are 1000 items in one chunk and 100th row failed insert, can we make the remaining 900 insert statements work?

Comment: if i use 1 item in chunk for better exception handling , i am not utilising the batch capabilities. right?

Comment: Your initial question was not about the failure case. If a skippable exception happens during the write, Spring Batch will scan the chunk for the faulty item (other items will be executed in separate transactions each). If you use set `commit-interval=1`, you will not benefit from batch updates (you will have 1000 transactions instead of 1). Please accept the answer if it helped (I believe it answered your initial question).